# If gives syntax error in Batch

Tags: batch-file

I have the following code in my batch file:

```
if "%startserver%"=="y"(
    java -Xmx1024M -jar craftbukkit.jar -o true
    exit
)
if "%startserver%"=="n"(
    exit
) else (
    goto invalid
)
```

It gives the following error when I run it:

```
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There needs to be a space  between the quotes `"` and the open parenthesis `(`, like so:

```
if "%startserver%"=="y" (
    java -Xmx1024M -jar craftbukkit.jar -o true
    exit
)

if "%startserver%"=="n" (
    exit
) else (
    goto invalid
)
```